# normalize boolean expression for caching reasons. is there a more efficient way than truth tables?

Tags: algorithm, caching, normalization, traversal, boolean-logic

My current project is an advanced tag database with boolean retrieval features. Records are being queried with boolean expressions like such (e.g. in a music database):

```
funky-music and not (live or cover)
```

which should yield all funky music in the music database but not live or cover versions of the songs.

When it comes to caching, the problem is that there exist queries which are equivalent but different in structure. For example, applying de Morgan's rule the above query could be written like this:

```
funky-music and not live and not cover
```

which would yield exactly the same records but of cause break caching when caching would be implemented by hashing the query string, for example.

Therefore, my first intention was to create a truth table of the query which could then be used as a caching key as equivalent expressions form the same truth table. Unfortunately, this is not practicable as the truth table grows exponentially with the number of inputs (tags) and I do not want to limit the number of tags used in one query.

Another approach could be traversing the syntax tree applying rules defined by the boolean algebra to form a (minimal) normalized representation which seems to be tricky too.

Thus the overall question is: Is there a practicable way to implement recognition of equivalent queries without the need of [circuit minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_minimization) or truth tables (edit: or any other algorithm which is NP-hard)?

The ne plus ultra would be recognizing already cached subqueries but that is no primary target.

Comment: use bitwise key -- eg.  set bit 0 if funky|bit 6 0 = live/1 = studio|bit 8 rap|bit 9 pop 

then you use bitwise operations to determine the key representation upon query
make sense?

Comment: this is a common pattern among mobile dev api's --  createScreen(long style_element) where the long style_element is the end result of said bitwise manipulations and dictates untold (truly lol) style elements for said Screen object

Comment: This would be a memory efficient way to store the information in the database. But that is a completely different topic.

Comment: each long represents a unique ID for a collection of chosen attributes -- maybe I do Not understand your question  lol  -- neeeed coffeeee

Comment: Well at least i don't get it:D

Answer (score 1):

A general and efficient algorithm to determine whether a query is equivalent to "False" could be used to solve NP-complete problems efficiently, so you are unlikely to find one.

You could try transforming your queries into a canonical form. Because of the above, there will be always be queries that are very expensive to transform into any given form, but you might find that, in practice, some form works pretty well most of the time - and you can always give up halfway through a transformation if it is becoming too hard.

You could look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram.

Comment: Creating those forms you mentioned involves the creation of a truth table also. Thus i could simply use the hash of a normalized form (inputs and combinations sorted) of the truth table as the caching key. Seems like the best way is creating a 'optimal' hash for queries covering less than 10 tags or so and for queries with more tags a simpler but not optimal algorithm.

Comment: You should be able to get any of these forms purely symbolically. Given any two expressions in any of these forms, you can work out the result of combining these expressions via AND or OR, and the result will be in the same form. You can do much the same thing with NOT. In some cases, the result will be complex, but it will be possible. For BDD there should be libraries to do this - see e.g.  http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/javabdd/BDD.html. So you can build a representation by combining the representations of individual variables.

Comment: But i do not see how this would circumvent the need of a NP-complete algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the queries into conjunctive normal form (CNF). It is a canonical, simple representation of boolean formulae that is normally the basis for SAT solvers.

Most likely "large" queries are going to have lots of conjunctions (rather than lots of disjunctions) so CNF should work well.

Comment: So building a CNF of a 'not worst case query' would be less complex than NP? Do you have a reference on how to implement the conversion? The common algorithm seems to involve truth tables which is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quine-McCluskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) algorithm should achieve what you are looking for. It is similiar to Karnaugh's Maps, but easier to [implement in software](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/qm/0.2).

Comment: Same as with antti.huima. It is too complex to be efficient, right?